# How to setup serial console on CentOS8/RedHat8?

Tags: linux, centos, serial-console

I rely on serial console on CentOS 8 to debug.
I ever set it up on CentOS 7 by editing file /etc/default/grub as below,

```
    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="crashkernel=auto console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8 intel_iommu=on modprobe.blacklist=nouveau,amdgpu"
    GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
    GRUB_TERMINAL="console serial"
    GRUB_SERIAL_COMMAND="serial --speed=115200 --unit=0 --word=8 --parity=no --stop=1"
```

and execute "grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg" then reboot. It worked like a charm
But this time it doesn't work on CentOS 8.
Could anyone shed light on it?

Comment: Can you check the grub settings? (Do you have another console?)

Comment: @K-att- I have two consoles. But I connect to ttyS0.

Comment: I think your problem is the grub. Can you check it via boot?

Comment: I edited /etc/default/grub as below, ````GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="$(sed 's, release .*$,,g' /etc/system-release)"
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=true
GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="console"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="crashkernel=auto resume=/dev/mapper/cl-swap rd.lvm.lv=cl/root rd.lvm.lv=cl/swap rhgb quiet console=ttyS0"
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
GRUB_ENABLE_BLSCFG=true
````. Is there something wrong?

Comment: I'm afraid the grub isn't changed. And you can check it via boot.

Comment: I got the dmesg as below, ```dmesg | grep tty
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-5.12.0+ root=/dev/mapper/cl-root ro crashkernel=auto console=ttyS0,115200
[    0.031255] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-5.12.0+ root=/dev/mapper/cl-root ro crashkernel=auto console=ttyS0,115200
[    1.179393] printk: console [ttyS0] enabled
[    4.567047] 00:03: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
[    4.574495] serial8250: ttyS1 at I/O 0x2f8 (irq = 3, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A```

Comment: And after boot the console connection works?

Comment: No. It is still the same.

Comment: Can you try it with ttyS1 ?

Comment: I edited /etc/default/grub as ```GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="crashkernel=auto console=ttyS1,115200"``` and ```GRUB_SERIAL_COMMAND="serial --speed=115200 --unit=1 --word=8 --parity=no --stop=1"```. It is the same. I can see nothing.

Comment: Until you can not connect via serial console to the working system, you can't connect from grub too.

Comment: I don't get your point, K-att-.

Comment: http://chrisreinking.com/how-to-enable-serial-console-output-in-centos/

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: systemctl status getty@ttyS0 ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129354/discussion-between-codexplorer-and-k-att).